# Python: json erasing vocabulary file data instead of writing

Tags: python, json

Hello and thanks for coming.
I have a problem, writing  JSON dict filled with data from the GUI: after execution of this script, i got an empty .json file, even if it was filled with something. Googled without any applicable result.

```
import easygui
import sys
from json import load, dump
from time import strftime, gmtime


def runTest():
    # This is not really correct, but it works.
    sys.argv = "Some Text"
    date = strftime("%d.%m.%Y", gmtime()) + " " + str(int(strftime("%H", gmtime())) + 4) + strftime(":%M", gmtime())
    test_case_area = easygui.buttonbox(
        "Welcome to Automation Testing Environment, please, select the testing area name:", "Autotests gentle robot",
        ("GUI", "EPG", "LCN"))
    stb = easygui.buttonbox("Please specify the STB type", "STB",
                            ("something_1", "something_2", "something_3", "something_4", "something_5", "something_6", "something_7"))
    platform = easygui.buttonbox("Please specify the {0} platform".format(stb), "{0} - Platform".format(stb),
                                 ("something_1", "something_2", "something_3", "something_4", "something_5"))
    full_platform = stb + "_" + platform
    msg = "Specify {0} parameters".format(full_platform)
    title = "{0} version information".format(full_platform)
    fieldNames = ["Software STB", "Hardware STB", "Module", "Software module", "Hardware module", "Tester", "Drive"]
    fieldValues = easygui.multenterbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
    test_conf_file_r = open("{0}:\\BBT2\\Configuration\\CP_PowerState.json".format(fieldValues[6]), "r")
    test_conf_vocab = load(test_conf_file_r)
    test_conf_vocab["platform"] = full_platform
    test_conf_vocab["SW_version"] = fieldValues[0]
    test_conf_vocab["HW_version"] = fieldValues[1]
    test_conf_vocab["test_name"] = test_case_area
    test_conf_vocab["disk"] = fieldValues[6]
    test_conf_file_w = open("{0}:\\BBT2\\Configuration\\CP_PowerState.json".format(fieldValues[6]), "w")
    dump(test_conf_vocab, test_conf_file_w)
```

After completing the .json part of the script at IDLE, i got an empty file again, though calling variables `test_conf_vocab` and `test_conf_file_w`  separately works fine. I know that i'm somehow messed up with `json.dump()`, i just can't see or Google any decent mistakes of my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the `test_conf_file_w` file object properly. Next time consider using `with` when working with files.

Comment: Hello wRar, that actually helped. I'll read more docs about using {with}. Thanks for a lesson.